# Analysing string in php

Tags: php, string, char

For a project, I have an input, which consists of numbers and letters, in a specific order, send from another web page. E.g. 7 numbers for an ID, a number followed by 2 letters for groups, and 1, 2, or 3 numbers for a room number.
To seperate them, I think I have to iterate through the whole string, see for each char if it is a number or a letter, and then use a lot of if/then functions to get the correct type.
Is there a better way to do this, or is this a good way to do it.

Comment: It sounds like a regular expression would be good for breaking the input into groups - try using `preg_match`.

Comment: there is a huge number of string functions. i think you should try regular expressions first.

Answer (score 1):

Using a regular expression should be the best solution here, as it would both tell you if the ID does match the wanted syntax, as well as getting the several parts of this ID in an array.

For the example you gave:

```
$idList = [
    '1AB12', // OK
    '1AB123', // OK
    '1AB1234', // KO
    'AB1234', //KO
    '12AB12', //KO
];

foreach ($idList as $id) {
    $isOk = preg_match('/^([0-9])([a-zA-Z]{2})([0-9]{1,3})$/', $id, $match);

    if ($isOk) {
        echo 'OK : ' . $id;
        var_dump($match);
    } else {
        echo 'KO : ' . $id;
    }
}
```